# Каким образом я могу реализовать запуск Minecraft

Tags: java, launcher

Создаю свой лаунчер для своего проекта и столкнулся с проблемой запуска игры. Пробовал уже смотеть чужие исходники, но нужной информации я найти не смог. Хотел бы спросить, как я могу реализовать сам запуск игры, используя хотя бы стандартную папку .minecraft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder mine=new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files (x86)/PathToFile/Minecraft.exe");
    mine.start();
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.print("Что то пошло не так");
}
```

Comment: А как я могу реализовать запуск игры, используя тот же JFrame. Мне нужно запускать сразу определенную версию игры с нужными мне параметрами (например сразу с никнеймом). Мне нужно запускать не сам лаунчер, а игру. Прошу прощения, что не уточнил это в своем вопросе.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @flawe, ProcessBuilder позволяет задать параметры при запуске приложения(через запятую, можно дописать). Насколько это все будет работать не знаю, надо тестить. По поводу JFrame - рисуйте кнопку, ставьте метод при котором при нажатии на кнопку будет запускаться игра.